# Controller registration failed Spring 4 using annotations with Zero xml configuration

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-14

I am trying to use Spring 4 with annotations(Zero xml configuration), Maven and IntelliJ, and at the end when I try to run the project, I realize that the controllers are not registered.

However, when I include `index.jsp` in root folder of views (`/webapp`)  it is easily recognised. But a call for controller fails. Any suggestions to overcome this issue would be highly welcome.

Here is my configuration class:

```
package com.megasystem.plano.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.megasystem.plano.web"})

public class PlanoConfig {
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
  }
}
```

And here is my WEB Initializer:

```
package com.megasystem.plano.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { PlanoConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
  }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
package com.megasystem.plano.web;

import com.megasystem.plano.bo.EmployeeBo;
import com.megasystem.plano.models.Employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.megasystem.plano.web")
public class EmployeeController {
  @Autowired
  EmployeeBo employeeBo;

  /*
   * This method will list all existing employees.
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String listEmployees(ModelMap model) {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeBo.listEmployees();
    model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
    return "all";
  }
}
```

And my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <groupId>com.megasystem.plano</groupId>  
  <artifactId>megasystem-plano</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>megasystem-plano Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Core Hibernate O/RM Functionality-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Hibernate's Bean Validator Engine-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependency start -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>plano</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then when I run the project without index.jsp in webapp, I see
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following initializer class

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { PlanoConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
  }
}
```